# Why fork() system call copies parent process memory?

Tags: linux, operating-system, fork, exec, copy-on-write

When we execute a process from a terminal, The termainal process does a `fork` and then `exec`. During fork, it creates its own copy which contains process specific information which in this case is `Bash` for example. Copying this memory can take some time even for some small processes which can delay the execution then Why do we copy memory during `fork`? How does it make sense to copy a large amount of data from a big process for a small process?

Comment: Linux does not copy all the memory straight away. It merely copies the mappings. The memory is shared between parent and child until there is a write to the memory. Only at that point is a copy of that particular page of memory is made. Search for "copy on write" for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  If this is a duplicate, I can close this question, if not, can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: The manual says that `fork` creates a "child process". Please look up what a child process is. HTH.

Comment: @cunev Please stop being rude and actually read the question. HTH HAND.

Comment: The linked answer here does not answer the question. The linked answer is HOW. The poster's question is WHY. Of course, if you post operating system questions with the "C" tag, that's what you're going to get.